# Migrating from Websphere 8.5 to Tomcat 8.5 API

Tags: java, tomcat, migration, websphere, server-migration

I am trying to migrate an piece of code which works on Websphere 8.5 to Tomcat 8.5.

There are a few imports that a piece of code uses:

```
import com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.callbackhandler.UNTGenerateCallbackHandler;
import com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.wssapi.WSSFactory;
import com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.wssapi.WSSGenerationContext;
import com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.wssapi.token.SecurityToken;
import com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.wssapi.token.UsernameToken
```

What can I use instead of these to make the code work?

The piece of the code that is using it is:

```
WSSFactory factory;
try {
    factory = WSSFactory.getInstance();
    WSSGenerationContext context = factory.newWSSGenerationContext();
    UNTGenerateCallbackHandler callbackHandler = new UNTGenerateCallbackHandler(userName, password);
    SecurityToken token = factory.newSecurityToken(UsernameToken.class, callbackHandler);
    context.add(token);
    context.process(soapMessageContext);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Tomcat and WebSphere have **very** different version schemes. You're going to find the Apache security implementation is *different* as well.

Comment: I know it will be different. I just want to know if there is any documentation for APIs jars etc so that I can use it.